# mocha init timeout with mocha-phantomjs

Tags: javascript, tdd, phantomjs, mocha.js

I have the following `testrunner.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Specs</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/css/mocha.css" />
    <script>
        function assert(expr, msg) {
            if (!expr) throw new Error(msg || 'failed');
        }
    </script>

    <script src="/client/lib/require.js" type="text/javascript" data-main="/client/specs/_runner.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `_runner.js` looks like this:

```
// Configure RequireJS
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/client',
    urlArgs: "v=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});

// Require libraries
require(['require', 'lib/chai', 'lib/mocha'], function (require, chai) {

    // Chai
    assert = chai.assert;
    should = chai.should();
    expect = chai.expect;

    // Mocha
    mocha.setup('bdd');


    // Require base tests before starting
    require(['specs/stringcalculator.specs'], function (person) {
        mocha.setup({ globals: ['hasCert'] });
        // Start runner
        if (window.mochaPhantomJS) {
            mochaPhantomJS.run();
        }
        else { mocha.run(); }
    });

});
```

The `StringCalculator.specs.js` is this:

```
define(['app/model/StringCalculator'], function () {

    describe("StringCalculator", function () {

        describe("when an empty string is passed in", function () {
            it("returns 0", function () {
                var result = StringCalculator.add("");
                assert(result === 0);
            });
        });

        describe("when a number is passed in", function () {
            it("returns the number", function () {
                var result = StringCalculator.add("2");
                assert(result === 2);
            });
        });

        describe("when string is passed in", function () {
            it("returns NaN", function () {
                var result = StringCalculator.add("a");
                assert(isNaN(result));
            });
        });

        describe("when '1,2' is passed in", function () {
            it("returns 3", function () {
                var result = StringCalculator.add("1,2");
                assert(result === 3);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the `StringCalculator.js` itself (from the mocha samples):

```
define([], function() {
    window.StringCalculator = StringCalculator = {
        add: function(inputString) {
            if (inputString === '') {
                return 0;
            }

            var result = 0;
            var inputStrings = inputString.split(',');

            for (var i = 0; i < inputStrings.length; i++) {
                result += parseInt(inputStrings[i]);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
});
```

When running the specs in a browser calling `testrunner.html`, everything works as expected.
When running `mocha-phantomjs client/specs/testrunner.html` on OS X, I get the following error:

`Failed to start mocha: Init timeout`

What may I'm missing here?

I also tried `mocha-phantomjs http://httpjs.herokuapp.com` which fails with the same error.

Update:
If I'm calling `mocha-phantomjs http://localhost:81/client/specs/testrunner.html` I also get the following error on the console:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

http://localhost:81/client/lib/chai.js?v=123423553533535:2601
Failed to start mocha: Init timeout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This file](https://github.com/metaskills/mocha-phantomjs/blob/master/test/requirejs.html) shows how to use it.

<strike>And for me, NodeJS 0.10.x does not seem to work with it. After switching to NodeJS 0.8.8, everything works as expected.</strike>

Using the current versions of mocha-phantomjs and PhantomJS now everything works fine.

Comment: Node 0.10.x users don't be completely discouraged -- I'm sure this was true at the time.  But today I'm on 0.10.13 and the solution above to use mochaPhantomJS.run() worked for me.

Comment: I still get random timeouts from time to time (no pun intended). Using the latest mocha-phantomjs too, etc. with a timeout of 10000.

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the same `Failed to start mocha` error when running `mocha-phantomjs` through the `grunt-mocha-phantomjs` npm package. Found the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/michaelcox/3800736#comment-859304).

Repeated here for reference:

To run with mocha-phantomjs, change

```
mocha.run();
```

to

```
if (mochaPhantomJS) {
  mochaPhantomJS.run();
}
else {
  mocha.run();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm seeing this problem too. But I just Installed Mocha-phantomjs and phantomjs using npm. I don't know where I can find SpecRunner.js and what exactly it does. Can you please explain?

Comment: @EternallyCurious, I'm not sure your question is within the scope of this one. Open a new one?

Comment: The link is now https://gist.github.com/michaelcox/3800736/#gistcomment-859304
(#comment has changed to #gistcomment)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this info, I tried the above but it failed in browser saying "mochaPhantomJS is undefined". A quick tweak as per below and it works well:

```
if(typeof(mochaPhantomJS)!=="undefined")
{
  mochaPhantomJS.run();
}
else
{
  mocha.run();
}
```