# Testing with Mocha and requirejs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, mocha.js

Im trying to get a testing environment for JavaScript set up but I am having some trouble with Mocha and requirejs. So far I have installed Mocha and that works as it should because I have tested it with the sample test from the documentation. The problem arises when I try and require some of the modules I want to test. At the top of my test.js file I have this:

```
var assert = require("assert"),
door = require( '../../assets/scripts/modules/door' );
```

But i get this error message in the console.

```
ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

Its referring to the first line of the door.js file that is.

```
define(['../utils/templating/hogan', '../models/ApiCaller', 'Backbone'], function (hogan, ApiCaller) {
```

I have also tried requiring requirejs like so...

```
var assert = require("assert"),
requirejs = require( '../../assets/scripts/require' ),
door = require( '../../assets/scripts/modules/door' );
```

As you have probably guessed im new to testing JavaScript and any explanation or solution would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

See if this gist https://gist.github.com/michaelcox/3800736 is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for that I will give it a try tomorrow when im back at work, do you think this will work for running mocha through the command line??

Comment: In my experience, there are two possibilities to run in command line. Possiblity 1 is using grunt and launch a http and possibility 2 is to run in casperjs. Which possibility do you have in mind?

Comment: I did come across Grunt and installed it when doing some research so i'll probably use that, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @DavidJones, I ended up using [`grunt-mocha-phantomjs`](https://github.com/jdcataldo/grunt-mocha-phantomjs) and my tests run in the browser *and* via command line. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18090584/742624 if you end up going that route.

Comment: @makla thanks for the feedback, I ending up using this https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-jasmine-runner-example